# Custom type Matrix*=int in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I use a custom complex type with Eigen.  This type is a wrapper around Boost.Multiprecision's `mpfr_float` type.  MPFR is a heap-allocated type in my uses (variable precision), so temporaries are *very* expensive.  Hence, I have all my constructors marked `explicit`.

I have a test case to check compilation using certain operations, a currently failing one which looks like this:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(self_multiplication_mpfr_int)
{
    using T = bertini::mpfr_complex;
    T q(1);
    int a(1);

    Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> A(2,2);
    A << T(2), T(1), T(1), T(2);

    A*=a; // this line fails to compile
}
```

I have provided a number of extensions to Eigen, most importantly to this post being

```
namespace eigen{ namespace internal{
template<> 
struct scalar_product_traits<int,bertini::complex> 
{
    enum { Defined = 1 };
    typedef bertini::complex ReturnType;
};

template<> 
struct scalar_product_traits<bertini::complex, int> 
{
    enum { Defined = 1 };
    typedef bertini::complex ReturnType;
};
}} // namespaces
```

See https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=111176 for more information on this `scalar_product_traits`.  I have added these for all sensible types in my world, `int`, `long`, `bmp::mpz_int`, `bmp::mpfr_float` (the corresponding real type), etc.

My compiler errors (clang on OSX) look like

```
test/library_compatibility/eigen.cpp:478:4: error: no viable overloaded '*='
            A*=a;
            ~^ ~
/Users/ofloveandhate/code/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:388:14: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const Scalar' (aka 'const bertini::complex') for 1st argument
Derived& operator*=(const Scalar& other);
         ^
/Users/ofloveandhate/code/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:183:14: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'EigenBase<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'int'
Derived& operator*=(const EigenBase<OtherDerived>& other);
         ^
```

I feel a MWE would be way too long to include here, so instead I can refer you to my repo, if necessary.  my Eigen version is 3.3, rev 10428.

My question is:
**Is this an Eigen thing, or do I need to add another bit of code to my Eigen extensions to make my custom type play nicely with *= and /=?**

Comment: It looks like this is just not implemented. But it should be relatively easy to do, since the binary `operator*` is implemented for mixed types (if they are compatible according to `scalar_product_traits`).

Comment: `A=A*a` should work though.

Comment: Related bug entry: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1416